# How to get part of Object from Array of Objects using typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have an array of Objects and I want to filter and ftech only part of object which I will be sending as a body parameter to an API.
Below is my code,however it returns me an array and inside that I have my object.I don't want it to be an array but just an Object.
How can I achieve this.

Original Array of Objects:

```
[ {
"flowId" : 11,
"flowName" : "jobtest003",
"version" : 1,
"ingestionFlowId" : "",
"jobCreatedDate" : "25-05-2020",
"jobUpdateDate" : "28-06-2020",
"jobLastRunDate" : "29-06-2020",
"active" : false,
"properties" : [ {
"id" : 12,
"key" : "sourceTable",
"value" : "job002",
"category" : "General Settings"
}, {
"id" : 13,
"key" : "Source",
"value" : "api",
"category" : "Source Properties"
},  {
"id" : 147,
"key" : "Target Path",
"value" : "/raw/au/jackson",
"category" : "Destination Properties"
} ]
}, {
"flowId" : 21,
"flowName" : "jobtest004",
"version" : 1,
"ingestionFlowId" : null,
"jobCreatedDate" : "25-05-2020",
"jobUpdateDate" : "28-06-2020",
"jobLastRunDate" : "29-06-2020",
"active" : false,
"properties" : [ {
"id" : 21,
"key" : "sourceTable",
"value" : "job003",
"category" : "General Settings"
}, {
"id" : 22,
"key" : "Source",
"value" : "api",
"category" : "Source Properties"
}, {
"id" : 23,
"key" : "Client ID",
"value" : "ebf73456-443e-4986-941b-057906d25e2f",
"category" : "Destination Properties"
},  {
"id" : 147,
"key" : "Target Path",
"value" : "/raw/au/jackson",
"category" : "Destination Properties"
} ]
}, {
"flowId" : 22,
"flowName" : "jobtest004",
"version" : 1,
"ingestionFlowId" : null,
"jobCreatedDate" : "25-05-2020",
"jobUpdateDate" : "28-06-2020",
"jobLastRunDate" : "29-06-2020",
"active" : false,
"properties" : [ {
"id" : 21,
"key" : "sourceTable",
"value" : "job003",
"category" : "General Settings"
}, {
"id" : 22,
"key" : "Source",
"value" : "api",
"category" : "Source Properties"
}, {
"id" : 23,
"key" : "Client ID",
"value" : "ebf73456-443e-4986-941b-057906d25e2f",
"category" : "Destination Properties"
},  {
"id" : 147,
"key" : "Target Path",
"value" : "/raw/au/jackson",
"category" : "Destination Properties"
} ]
} ]
```

The result I want :

```
{
  "flowId" : 20,
  "flowName" : "jobtest004",
  "version" : 1,
  "ingestionFlowId" : null,
  "jobCreatedDate" : "25-05-2020",
  "jobUpdateDate" : "28-06-2020",
  "jobLastRunDate" : "29-06-2020",
  "active" : false,
  "properties" : [ {
    "id" : 21,
    "key" : "sourceTable",
    "value" : "job003",
    "category" : "General Settings"
  }, {
    "id" : 22,
    "key" : "Source",
    "value" : "api",
    "category" : "Source Properties"
  }, {
    "id" : 23,
    "key" : "Client ID",
    "value" : "ebf73456-443e-4986-941b-057906d25e2f",
    "category" : "Destination Properties"
  },  {
    "id" : 147,
    "key" : "Target Path",
    "value" : "/raw/au/jackson",
    "category" : "Destination Properties"
  } ]
}
```

The result I am getting:

```
[{
  "flowId" : 20,
  "flowName" : "jobtest004",
  "version" : 1,
  "ingestionFlowId" : null,
  "jobCreatedDate" : "25-05-2020",
  "jobUpdateDate" : "28-06-2020",
  "jobLastRunDate" : "29-06-2020",
  "active" : false,
  "properties" : [ {
    "id" : 21,
    "key" : "sourceTable",
    "value" : "job003",
    "category" : "General Settings"
  }, {
    "id" : 22,
    "key" : "Source",
    "value" : "api",
    "category" : "Source Properties"
  }, {
    "id" : 23,
    "key" : "Client ID",
    "value" : "ebf73456-443e-4986-941b-057906d25e2f",
    "category" : "Destination Properties"
  },  {
    "id" : 147,
    "key" : "Target Path",
    "value" : "/raw/au/jackson",
    "category" : "Destination Properties"
  } ]
}]
```

I don't want my result to be an array instead I just want it to be an Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use `find` method on the Array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Thanks.I was complicating my task by looping and filtering the array.Find is simple and works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Use find method of array as follows.

```
var array = your data;

var object_needed = array.find(d=>d.flowId == 21)//use required id in place of 21 or use required property in place of .flowIf
//console.log(object_needed)
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

With your explanation if I have understood right
Array.prototype.filter will always return an array only, you have to use array index to get the object out of array

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` method to convert array into object.

```js
const convertArrayToObject = (array, key) => {
      const initialValue = {};
      return array.reduce((obj, item) => {
        return {
          ...obj,
          [item[key]]: item,
        };
      }, initialValue);
    };

let testData = [ { "flowId" : 11, "flowName" : "jobtest003", "version" : 1, "ingestionFlowId" : "", "jobCreatedDate" : "25-05-2020", "jobUpdateDate" : "28-06-2020", "jobLastRunDate" : "29-06-2020", "active" : false, "properties" : [ { "id" : 12, "key" : "sourceTable", "value" : "job002", "category" : "General Settings" }, { "id" : 13, "key" : "Source", "value" : "api", "category" : "Source Properties" }, { "id" : 147, "key" : "Target Path", "value" : "/raw/au/jackson", "category" : "Destination Properties" } ] }, { "flowId" : 21, "flowName" : "jobtest004", "version" : 1, "ingestionFlowId" : null, "jobCreatedDate" : "25-05-2020", "jobUpdateDate" : "28-06-2020", "jobLastRunDate" : "29-06-2020", "active" : false, "properties" : [ { "id" : 21, "key" : "sourceTable", "value" : "job003", "category" : "General Settings" }, { "id" : 22, "key" : "Source", "value" : "api", "category" : "Source Properties" }, { "id" : 23, "key" : "Client ID", "value" : "ebf73456-443e-4986-941b-057906d25e2f", "category" : "Destination Properties" }, { "id" : 147, "key" : "Target Path", "value" : "/raw/au/jackson", "category" : "Destination Properties" } ] }, { "flowId" : 22, "flowName" : "jobtest004", "version" : 1, "ingestionFlowId" : null, "jobCreatedDate" : "25-05-2020", "jobUpdateDate" : "28-06-2020", "jobLastRunDate" : "29-06-2020", "active" : false, "properties" : [ { "id" : 21, "key" : "sourceTable", "value" : "job003", "category" : "General Settings" }, { "id" : 22, "key" : "Source", "value" : "api", "category" : "Source Properties" }, { "id" : 23, "key" : "Client ID", "value" : "ebf73456-443e-4986-941b-057906d25e2f", "category" : "Destination Properties" }, { "id" : 147, "key" : "Target Path", "value" : "/raw/au/jackson", "category" : "Destination Properties" } ] } ];

    console.log(
      convertArrayToObject(testData,'flowId')
    );
```

[click here for detailed explanation](https://dev.to/afewminutesofcode/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object-in-javascript-25a4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use find method as below which will return only object

```
arrayOfData.find(function(obj){
return obj.Id == 11
})
```

or

```
arrayOfData.find(obj => obj.Id == 11)
```